# How to detect shopware exact version using shopware url

Tags: api, curl, rest, shopware

Sometimes in shopware 6 some shops uses v1 api and some shops uses v2/v3 api ,so how can we trigger that ?

Answer (score 1):

As of Shopware 6.4.0 the API versioning was removed. It is now possible to test for specific Shopware core and plugin versions using API expectations.

Like this:

```
GET /api/test
sw-expect-packages: shopware/core:~6.4
```

[Read the docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/api-versioning) for more details.